# Why have I not been awarded the bronze badge for the FINDSTR tag?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

I reached 100 upvotes on 30 non-community wiki answers to [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) questions at least 4 days ago. I'm now up to 102 upvotes. But I still have not been awarded the bronze badge for that tag.

I've seen meta Q&A referring to a delay of no more than a day to be awarded a tag badge. Is my situation a bug? or is there a valid reason why I have not been awarded the badge?

Comment: As findstr os a Windows terminal command and many questions here are on the syntax shouldn't most of the questions be closed as off topic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) tag is only used on 84 questions, but tag badges are only awarded for tags which are used on at least 100 questions.

It's subtly mentioned on the [list of tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags):

> If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

Once the number of [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) questions reaches 100, the system should automatically award you the badge.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure that is subtle, but I definitely missed that important point. I think I skipped the intro paragraph and skipped to the requirements for each badge when I read the descriptions.